# Access Symfony2 Session from another php script

Tags: php, symfony

I want to access symfony2 session variables from another php script so I've defined in controller:

```
$session = $this->container->get('session');

$session->set('name', 'jhon');
```

and in another php I've tried to access `name` like:

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You're assuming that symfony will simply use the `'name'` index to store the session value. This is not correct. Dump the $_SESSION array in full, and you'll see what data you have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony (by default) store session data in a particular key.

Try this:

```
echo $_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['name'];
```